# C language order of precedence

Tags: c, expression, undefined-behavior, evaluation

```
a = 5;
c = (b =a+2) - (a=1);
```

In book c programming a modern approach by kn king it is written that the effect of executing the second statement will result in 6 or 2 as it is undefined behavior of c but in other books like c by Dennis  it is written that it will be executed from left to right. Which one is correct?

Comment: it is undefined behavior.

Comment: What the heck is "C by Dennis"? If you're talking about [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language), it doesn't say anything about left-to-right execution.

Comment: Are you sure King says that? Which edition and page number?

Comment: There is no guarantee that the result will be 6 or 2 — they're possible values of the result, but so are 0 and 256 and any other number.  The code exhibits undefined behaviour.  Search for 'nasal demons'.

Answer (score 2):

In the above case,

```
 c=(b=a+2) -(a=1);
```

the value of `a` is being changed and being read without a sequence point in between, so it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, Annex §J.2, *Undefined behavior*

> A side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect
>   on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>   object.

Also related, from chapter §6.5

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.<sup>85)</sup> Except as specified
>   later, side effects and value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced.<sup>86)</sup>

So, there's no guarantee which subexpression will get evaluated first.

Comment: Close, but the evaluation is not (necessarily) simultaneous.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sir, that is why I put that in _italics_, can you suggest an alternative wording?

Comment: Drop the word "simultaneously", just say that there's no sequence point.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, any better now?